# Given two vectors, add another to express $\Bbb R^3$ standard generators as linear combinations of all three vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

This is an exercise problem out of 'Coding The Matrix' that I'm really stuck on at the moment:

> You are given the vectors $[1,1,1], [0.4,1.3,-2.2]$. Add one additional vector and express each of the standard generators of $\Bbb R^3$  as a linear combination of the three vectors.

I've been trying to find hints in the text or via Google on how to approach this, but I'm coming up with nothing at the moment. Can anyone offer a bump in the right direction or how to think about this?

Edit:

Thanks @pjs36, @dxiv, & @T.K, for your comments so far. I can see now the intuition some of you are getting at (eg finding another vector outside of the span of the first two). Am I missing something though where this problem should be 'easily solvable' outside of using GJ elimination? At this point in the textbook working with and solving matrices hasn't really been introduced yet. So I wonder if I'm missing a more 'obvious' solution?

Comment: Does it make sense that the two vectors (you can scale the second up to $[4,\, 13,\, -22]$ if you like) span a two-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^3$? Try and find something in $\Bbb R^3$ that's *not* in their span.

Comment: If you picked the third vector randomly, chances are virtually 100% that it would be a correct answer. Hint: choose *any* non-zero vector which is not a linear combination of the given ones.

Comment: re the edit, no, I don't think there's any sort of shortcut -- just bear down and solve a $3 \times 3$ system (with Gaussian elimination or otherwise) once the time comes. Even if matrices were introduced, it wouldn't really save you any effort; row reducing (GJ in disguise) and computing inverses are fairly labor-intensive. It's not glamorous, but it *should* be straight forward.

Comment: @pjs36 okay, great, thanks again. Glad to know I'm not missing anything then -- feels a little out of place as a question but I guess that's just how it is atm.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem requires you to find an another basis for $\boldsymbol R^3$. You can choose any vector in $\boldsymbol R^3$ which is lineary independent from given two vectors $v_1=[1, 1, 1],\ v_2=[0.4,1.3,-2.2]$(I think $v_3=[1,1,0]$ can be chosen but,you can choose any independent vector for your convenience). And then find representation of canonical basis $\boldsymbol C = \lbrace c_1=[1,0,0],c_2=[0,1,0],c_3=[0,0,1] \rbrace$ for $\boldsymbol R^3$ as this new basis, say 
$\boldsymbol B=\lbrace v_1,v_2,v_3\rbrace$. This procedure can be done by solving linear equations $ c_1 = \alpha_1v_1 + \alpha_2v_2 + \alpha_3v_3 \nonumber \\
c_2 = \beta_1v_1 + \beta_2v_2 + \beta_3v_3  \nonumber \\
c3 = \gamma_1v_1 + \gamma_2v_2 +\gamma_3v_3$

Each eqautions can be solved using Gaussian Elimination or if these equations are simple, you can just manipulate coefficient directly

Comment: Generally speaking this is just finding an another basis of given vector space(one basis is given and you need to find another basis) and find the matrix representation of coordinate isomorphism with respect to these two basis.